# In reference to

Tags: sentence-construction

Do you think the sentence would be incomplete if I omit the part 'in reference'?

> With the rise of the Renaissance, new interest sparked in reference to
>   the physical world.

My sentence : With the rise of the Renaissance, new interest sparked to the physical world.

http://www.sparknotes.com/history/european/scientificrevolution/context.html

Comment: Second sentence made it seem like the interest went to the physical world (i.e the physical world now has the interest). I would stay with your current sentence.

Comment: Is there a source for the original phrase?

Comment: *Spark* in this sense is ordinarily a transitive verb: *The Renaissance's rediscovery of classical sculpture **sparked a new interest** in the physical world.*

Comment: Without further context, any rendering of the sentence lacks explanation of what _kind_ of interest. And the aithor must be speaking of a particular kind of "interest"— it's not as if people had _no_ interest whatsoever in the physical world _before the Renaissance_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't lose "in reference". Lose "reference to".

With the rise of the Renaissance, new interest sparked in the physical world.

But even that is a bit unintuitive. Combining it with what interest you are talking about would be a good idea. For example:

With the rise of the Renaissance, people sparked an interest in painting the physical world.

Comment: +1.  Another way, that doesn't insert "people" but keeps the passive voice of the original: "With the rise of the Renaissance, interest in the physical world was sparked."